# Proxy pass 404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu) but the slashes are in the right places

Tags: nginx

In a file called `test.conf`in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, I have:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test;
    root /var/www;
    location /some/path/ {
        proxy_pass http://www.example.com/link/;
    }

}
```

After `sudo nginx -s reload` when I try to go to http://1xx.xx.xx.xx/ I have got the usaul nginx welcom page but at

```
http://1xx.xx.xx.xx/some/path/
```

I have got a:

```
404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

I have tried everything but I can't really understand where is the problem.

Comment: What does the logs show?

Comment: The server name `test` does not match the requested host name which is `1xx.xx.xx.xx`. Is this the only `server` block? Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to find out. Also, check the **error log**, as it will tell you which `server` block Nginx is using to process the request.

Comment: @vidarlo thanks for you comment, if I `cat /var/log/nginx/access.log` I just see `"GET /some/path HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "-" etc. etc.` while no error is shown in the if I `cat /var/log/nginx/errors.log`

Comment: @RichardSmith I didn't know that useful command,  it's embarassing to admit but I completely forgot to delete the default configuration that was overwriting the conf.d. I am really greateful for your help, so if you can formalize the comment into an answer I will accept it and I am sure that someone else will find it useful. Thanks again.